# Dynamically add and delete text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code that i used to create the functionality is below

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamically Add and Delete Textbox using jQuery</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<style>
@font-face{font-family: Lobster;src: url('Lobster.otf');}
body{width:750px;margin:0px auto;}
.space{margin-bottom: 4px;}
.txt{width:250px;border:1px solid #00BB64; height:30px;border-radius:3px;font-family: Lobster;font-size:20px;color:#00BB64;}
p{font-family: Lobster;font-size:35px; text-align:center;}
.but{width:250px;background:#00BB64;border:1px solid #00BB64;height:40px;border-radius:3px;color:white;margin-top:10px;}
</style>
<script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Dynamically Add and Delete Textbox using jQuery</p>
<div id="advice" style="width: 400px; height: auto;">
  <form>
  <div id="button_pro">
    <div class='space' id='input_1'>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Description </th>
        <th> section </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input id="input_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>
        <td><input id="input_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>
        <td><input id="input_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>

        <td><img class="add right" src="images/add.png" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>


    </div>
   </div>   
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='but'/>
 </form>    
</div>

<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    var id=2,txt_box;
    $('#button_pro').on('click','.add',function(){
          $(this).remove();
          txt_box='<div class="space" id="input_'+id+'" ><table><tr><th>  Name </th><th> Description </th><th> Section </th></tr>   <tr><td><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><img class="remove" src="images/remove.png" /></td><td><img class="add right" src="images/add.png" /></td></tr></table></div>';
          $("#button_pro").append(txt_box);
          id++;
    });

    $('#button_pro').on('click','.remove',function(){
            var parent=$(this).parent().prev().attr("id");
            var parent_im=$(this).parent().attr("id");
            $("#"+parent_im).slideUp('medium',function(){
                $("#"+parent_im).remove();
                if($('.add').length<1){
                    $("#"+parent).append('<img src="images/add.png" class="add right"/>');
                }
            });
            });


});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem here is the plus image functionality works fine where as the minus image that is to remove the text boxes is not working.

When i remove the  tag from the text box variable and add it before the  tags in the text box variable it works properly.

I am not sure why the  tag change affects the functionality of the remove function

Comment: I could see duplicate `ids` in example provided..

Comment: Duplicate id in the sense. Can you please explain a bit elobrately

Comment: You must not have same `ids` in same document. `Id` must be unique..

Comment: [id: The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified you code and made it simpler. You can use the **closest** function to make things easy.

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/4b5wdev2/

CSS:

```
@font-face{font-family: Lobster;src: url('Lobster.otf');}
body{width:750px;margin:0px auto;}
.space{margin-bottom: 4px;}
.txt{width:250px;border:1px solid #00BB64; height:30px;border-radius:3px;font-family: Lobster;font-size:20px;color:#00BB64;}
p{font-family: Lobster;font-size:35px; text-align:center;}
.but{width:250px;background:#00BB64;border:1px solid #00BB64;height:40px;border-radius:3px;color:white;margin-top:10px;}
```

JS:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var id=2,txt_box;
    $('#button_pro').on('click','.add',function(){
          $(this).remove();
          txt_box='<div class="space" id="input_'+id+'" ><table><tr><th>  Name </th><th> Description </th><th> Section </th></tr>   <tr><td><input id="name_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><input id="desc_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><input id="section_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><img class="remove" src="images/remove.png" /></td><td class="addTD"><img class="add right" src="images/add.png" /></td></tr></table></div>';
          $("#button_pro").append(txt_box);
          id++;
    });

    $('#button_pro').on('click','.remove',function(){

            var parent = $(this).closest(".space");
           var parentPrev = $(parent).prev().find(".addTD");

            $(parent).slideUp('medium',function(){
                $(parent).remove();
                if($('.add').length < 1){
                    $(parentPrev).append('<img src="images/add.png" class="add right"/>');
                }
            });
            });


});
```

HTML:

```
<p>Dynamically Add and Delete Textbox using jQuery</p>
<div id="advice" style="width: 400px; height: auto;">
  <form>
  <div id="button_pro">
    <div class='space' id='input_1'>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Description </th>
        <th> section </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input id="name_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>
        <td><input id="desc_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>
        <td><input id="section_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>

        <td class="addTD"><img class="add right" src="images/add.png" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>


    </div>
   </div>   
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='but'/>
 </form>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look demo to add and remove dynamic input field:

```js
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
    
    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });
    
    $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
<div id="p_scents">
  <p>
      <label for="p_scnts">
        <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />         </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Op's example is different than yours !

Comment: Yeap i just pass the logic now you can append your HTML UI whatever you want it there. let me know if you've any trouble

Answer (score 0):

See the below demo

http://jsfiddle.net/y7g9no9L/

Just add the following line in the `.remove` click function

```
$('#button_pro').on('click','.remove',function(){
            $(this).parent().closest(".space").remove();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-*` attributes for your labels and make sure you don't duplicate ids. The best way to have is to have ids as in data-* attrs so that they can have dupes.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    
  $('#button_pro').on('click','.add',function(){
    var id=$('#button_pro > div.space').data('id')*1+1;
    $(this).remove();
    var txt_box='<div class="space" data-id="'+id+'" id="input_'+id+'" ><table><tr><th>  Name </th><th> Description </th><th> Section </th></tr>   <tr><td><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/></td><td><img class="remove" src="images/remove.png" /></td><td><img class="add right" src="images/add.png" /></td></tr></table></div>';
    $("#button_pro").append(txt_box);

  });

  $('#button_pro').on('click','.remove',function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('div.space').prev();
    $(this).closest('#button_pro > div.space').slideUp('medium',function(){
      if($('div.space').length>1){
        if(this == $('#button_pro > div.space:last')[0])
          id.find('td').last().append('<img src="images/add.png" class="add right"/>');
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
@font-face{font-family: Lobster;src: url('Lobster.otf');}
body{width:750px;margin:0px auto;}
.space{margin-bottom: 4px;}
.txt{width:250px;border:1px solid #00BB64; height:30px;border-radius:3px;font-family: Lobster;font-size:20px;color:#00BB64;}
p{font-family: Lobster;font-size:35px; text-align:center;}
.but{width:250px;background:#00BB64;border:1px solid #00BB64;height:40px;border-radius:3px;color:white;margin-top:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Dynamically Add and Delete Textbox using jQuery</p>
<div id="advice" style="width: 400px; height: auto;">
  <form>
    <div id="button_pro">
      <div class='space' data-id='1'>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Description </th>
            <th> section </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="input_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>
            <td><input id="input_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>
            <td><input id="input_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/></td>
            <td><img class="add right" src="images/add.png" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>   
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='but'/>
  </form>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create index.html and add jQuery libary, textbox and an image(addition).

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Textbox addition and Deletion using jQuery</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Dynamically Add and Delete Textbox using jQuery</p>
<div id="advice" style="width: 400px; height: auto;margin:0px auto;">
  <form>
  <div id="button_pro">
    <div class='space' id='input_1'>
        <input id="input_1" type="text" name="val[]" class='left txt'/>
        <img src="images/add.png" />
    </div>
   </div>    
    <input type='submit' value='Kiss Me!' class='but'/>
 </form>    
</div>
</body>
```

Now add below css styles in the head section to add a beauty.

```
<style>
@font-face{font-family: Lobster;src: url('Lobster.otf');}
body{width:750px;margin:0px auto;}
.space{margin-bottom: 4px;}
.txt{width:250px;border:1px solid #00BB64; height:30px;border-radius:3px;font-family: Lobster;font-size:20px;color:#00BB64;}
p{font-family: Lobster;font-size:35px; text-align:center;}
.but{width:250px;background:#00BB64;border:1px solid #00BB64;height:40px;border-radius:3px;color:white;margin-top:10px;}
</style>
```

Now we come into party of jQuery. First task is when we clicked on plus image it will dynamically add textboxes into the form.

```
var id=2,txt_box;
    $('#button_pro').on('click','.add',function(){
          $(this).remove();
          txt_box='<div class="space" id="input_'+id+'" ><input type="text" name="val[]" class="left txt"/><img src="images/remove.png" class="remove"/><img class="add right" src="images/add.png" /></div>';
          $("#button_pro").append(txt_box);
          id++;
    });
```

[See the Demo](http://www.smarttutorials.net/dynamically-add-and-remove-textbox-using-jquery/)

[DEMO 1](http://www.encodedna.com/2013/07/dynamically-add-remove-textbox-control-using-jquery.htm)